Using CONTAINSSTRING to create relationships between two data tables
I'm connecting to a SharePoint list with choice columns. One of the list columns is a choice column titled "Assigned to" with the option to select one or more city from a list. In PBI, that data comes over into the columns and rows as a list of cities separated by commas. I need to isolate the data in PBI based on single cities to identify what's assigned to each city, even if it's assigned to other cities as well.
I've created a table with one column, listing out each city individually in the rows. I created a relationship with my SharePoint list table and I'm able to isolate the data with a single city in the "Assigned To" column. However, all the rows of data assigned to multiple cities still get lumped together. If I use the relationship table I built, the items assigned to multiple cities show up, but in my visuals they show as assigned to a blank. If I use the "Assigned To" column in my data table, they show up as new entries for each combination of cities that was selected in the SharePoint list so I'm unable to compile all of the data for each individual city. I was able to use CONTAINSSTRING to create measures for isolating some of the data but this only works for very specific data points and doesn't work for my visuals.
I included two snapshots of what I'm seeing. The first snap shows what I get if I use the "Assigned To" column in my primary data table. The second snap shows what I get if I use my relationship table. You'll noticed between the two photos, using Anchorage as an example, that the relationship table isn't accounting for every item assigned to Anchorage. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!


